# How can I define certain value to its key with equal sigma index?

Tags: python

I want to set the transition of start state 's value, with the key of sigma in dfa dictionary. if the certain indexes of sigma equals with the value of transitions.
for example, i want to set if sigma[0] == 0 weach is the value of A in transitions then set the values of zero  in A as value for key sigma[0].

```
nfa = {
    'Q': ['A', 'B'],
    'sigma': [0, 1],
    'start': 'A',
    'transitions': {
        'A': {0: ['B'],
              1: []
              },
        'B': {
            0: [],
            1: ['A', 'B']
        }
    },
    'final_state': ['B']
}

# print(nfa)
Q1 = []
Q1.append(nfa['start'])
print(Q1)
for i in nfa['start']:
    if nfa['transitions']['A'].values() == 0:
        print(nfa['transitions']['A'].values())
    if [nfa['start'] == Q1 == nfa['transitions'].keys()]:
        dfa = {nfa['start']:
            {nfa['sigma'][0]: [nfa['transitions']['A'].values()],
            nfa['sigma'][1]: [nfa['transitions']['A'].values()]
            }
            
        }
        print(dfa)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you clarify what you mean by "key of sigma"?

Comment: Can you please provide an example input and expected output?

Comment: Thanks! I mean that the key in dfa dictionary for the key of nfa['start'] will be nfa['sigma'] and the values that i want to put, are values of transition weach the transitions value is equal with start state, and after that equals with sigma 's value –

Comment: for i.e.
start state is A
sigma[0] is 0
i want to say when transition.value == start state and when the value of A in transition part == sigma[0]
then{ sigma[0] : transition[A].value weach keys is qual to sigma[0]
i cant say that fluently

Answer (score 0):

You can create the transition alphabet before creating the NFA. That allows you to refer to it within the `transitions` dictionary:

```py
sigma = [0, 1]
nfa = {
    'Q': ['A', 'B'],
    'sigma': sigma,
    'start': 'A',
    'transitions': {
        'A': {sigma[0]: ['B'],
              sigma[1]: []
              },
        'B': {
            sigma[0]: [],
            sigma[1]: ['A', 'B']
        }
    },
    'final_state': ['B']
}
```